# root logger not respecting log level Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get my head around Python logging in general and I have created a small code to do so. Below is my main code file:

```
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('logging-2.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger('main')
import auxillary


logger.info("Info message from main file")
logger.warning("This is a warning message from main file")
```

My logging configuration file goes as follows:

```
[loggers]
keys=root, main

[handlers]
keys=mainhandler, roothandler

[formatters]
keys=mainformatter

[logger_root]
level=ERROR
handlers = roothandler

[logger_main]
level=DEBUG
handlers=mainhandler
qualname=main
propagate=1

[handler_roothandler]
class=StreamHandler
args=(sys.stdout,)

[handler_mainhandler]
class=FileHandler
formatter=mainformatter
args=("main.log",)

[formatter_mainformatter]
format=%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s
```

And below is the code of the `auxillary.py` file:

```
import logging

module_logger = logging.getLogger('main.auxiliary')

module_logger.info("Info statement from auxillary function")
module_logger.warning("warning message from auxillary function")
```

When I run the code I get the following output:

```
Info statement from auxillary function
warning message from auxillary function
Info message from main file
This is a warning message from main file
```

And the contents of my `main.log` file is as follows:

```
2019-07-28 16:52:05,710 - main.auxiliary - INFO - Info statement from auxillary function
2019-07-28 16:52:05,710 - main.auxiliary - WARNING - warning message from auxillary function
2019-07-28 16:52:05,710 - main - INFO - Info message from main file
2019-07-28 16:52:05,710 - main - WARNING - This is a warning message from main file
```

In other words, even after setting the log level to ERROR for the root logger it is printing all the messages.

Any idea why is this happening? How should I force the root logger to only print messages from error and above even if propagate is true for it.